# How to copy multiple files with different extensions using Java 8?

Tags: java, nio

I have different kind of files in my working directory (.log, .xml,.opf so on). I need to copy them for another folder.But only one file is copied as I understand this is because of  using `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`in copy method. 
Here is my Java code

```
String currentDirectory = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath()).getPath();

tempDirPath = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(jobFolder).resolve("output"));

try {
            Files.copy(Paths.get(currentDirectory +File.separator+"content.xml"), tempDirPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            Files.copy(Paths.get(currentDirectory +File.separator+"content.smil"), tempDirPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            Files.copy(Paths.get(currentDirectory +File.separator+"content.opf"), tempDirPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            Files.copy(Paths.get(currentDirectory +File.separator+"content.ncx"), tempDirPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance..!

Comment: `REPLACE_EXISTING` should mean if there already is a content.xml that one will be replaced but if you copy a content.smil that won't replace a content.xml. But if you provide a target file name and that's the same for each file then yes, you'll replace that. That's not a problem of Java though but how the filesystem handles things in general (you can't have 2 files with the same name in a folder). If that's your problem, then you'll need to provide a unique name yourself.

Comment: Do you want to copy just some selected files from the source directory into the destination directory? If you want to copy all of them you can simply use the FileUtils method -  FileUtils.copyDirectory( directory, destination )

Comment: Note: You should be using `Paths.get(currentDirectory, "context.xml")` instead of using `File.separator`. This is what the `Paths.get()` varargs is for.

Comment: alternatively you could use apache's FileUtils to copy an entire folder (i.e. using copyDirectory method)

Comment: @woytech No..Ijust wanted to copy selected files.. So copyDirectory can not be used..RealSkeptic I got it for forward slash and without giving it as '/' I used this method if symbol may vary with os .. Nafas I try to use only java here. Thomas Thank you for your explanation.It is highly useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Files.copy` second parameter is not directory, but file name.

It should be:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(currentDirectory +File.separator+"content.ncx"), tempDirPath.resolve("content.ncx"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: This is giving me correct output.And when I used tempDirPath as second parameter it worked only for one file reason may be the @Thomas explanation.. Thank you